# Vue.JS import custom module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, vue-component

I have created a module *greatings.js* like this one:

```
function greatings() {
  this.hello = function() {
    return 'hello!';
  }

  this.goodbye = function() {
    return 'goodbye!';
  }
}

module.exports = greatings;
```

Then I imported it into *main.js* in VUE.JS just like:

```
import greatings from './assets/js/greatings';
Vue.use(greatings);
```

Now I would like to use it in my components but if I do it I got an error:

```
  mounted() {
    this.greatings.hello();
  }
```

> ERROR: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined"

How to fix it and be able to use my greatings?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 2):

greatings.js file should be like this

```
export default {
  hello() {
    return "hello";
  },
  goodbye() {
    return "goodbye!";
  }
};
```

and import in any file you want to use like this

import greatings from './assets/js/greatings';

and call any function do you want. remove this function `Vue.use(greatings);`

Comment: Thanks. How to call the *hello* function from mounted(){} ? greatings.hello() ? I got error...

Comment: you can call hello like this greatings.hello();

Comment: mounted(){
    greatings.hello();
  }

Comment: _assets_js_greatings__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10___default.a.hello is not a function"

Comment: Maybe it's a webpack error... I copied the same code ad above in my component. It loads greatings.js but I got the error in mount()

Answer (score 1):

When using Vue.use() to register a custom plugin, it has to define an install() function, which is called by Vue. From docs:

> A Vue.js plugin should expose an install method. The method will be called with the Vue constructor as the first argument, along with possible options.

See the provided example, for all the options you have when creating a custom plugin: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks Igor, this is very helpful, but I'm trying to reuse my old script; a plugin requires too many changes. I'll evaluate if I really need a plugin. Thanks for suggestion