# how to import file from "src" folder to "public" folder in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create SPA\PWA using Vue Js.

I want to import a file of functions to `public` folder from `src` folder.

[image]

so i do this:

**index.html file in public folder:**

[image]

in the first time i get this err: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` then I added `type="module"` but now i get this err: `GET http://localhost:8080/src/scripts/sc.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

how can i fix that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: @ThomasJunk In the ```sc.js``` file there is a function ```getOS`` that determines the os of the device` I want to use to accept only Android and iOS users to use the site.

Comment: Okay. My bad. I asked imprecise. Why do you want to "import" the package within the context of the index.html in contrast to just import it in your `main.js` as any other function? What makes you think you have to solve your problem this way and not in another way? Maybe the problems you are facing stem from choosing the wrong approach?

Comment: If you want to use imports in your script, you should build a js bundle with webpack/babel or similar. Your frontend code can't known about your source code files tree.

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867833/vue-js-import-custom-module

Comment: @ThomasJunk Because I don't know how to do this :( ... Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Roberto no. I don't think these questions are related. Only inasfar that someone wants to import code somewhere which doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Adam Oh. I did help you already 

Comment: @ThomasJunk can you show me an example

Comment: The problem is, that you are on the wrong track. I hoped you got the point earlier.

Comment: @Adam use npm package for your os detection

Answer (score 1):

Just import your `script.js` in `main.js` or which is entry level file you need to import inside it.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you want only ios and android view your app you can use an package like vue-mobile-detection or device-detector-js

```
npm i vue-mobile-detection
```

Plugin installation

```
import VueMobileDetection from "vue-mobile-detection";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueMobileDetection);

/* After the install you can use this.$isMobile() in all your vue components */
```

Using the plugin

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Use in template -->
    <div v-if="$isMobile()">MOBILE</div>
    <div v-else>DESKTOP OR TABLET (Denied Access)</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  created() {
    // Use in js
    console.log(this.$isMobile());
  }
};
</script>
```

also you can use route or your own isMobile function please refer to this thread

[Display different Vuejs components for mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515023/display-different-vuejs-components-for-mobile-browsers)